# Undeclared identifier in Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c

Am getting an undeclared identifier problem in my code. Have commented the compiler messages.

Main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

     @autoreleasepool {

         NSMutableArray *stocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

         NSMutableDictionary *stock;

        stock = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [stock setObject:@"AAPL" 
                  forKey:@"symbol"];

        [stock setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:200]
                                        forKey:@"shares"];
                                [stocks addObject:stock];

         stock = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
         [stock = setObject:@"GOOG" // use of undeclared identifier 'setObject'
                     forKey:@"symbol"];
         [stock = setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:160] // use of undeclared identifier     'setObject'
                  forKey:@"shares"];
        [stocks addObject:stock];

        [stocks writeToFile:@"/tmp/stocks/plist" 
                 atomically:YES];



        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the equals sign..

```
 [stock **=** setObject:@"GOOG" // use of undeclared identifier 'setObject'
                 forKey:@"symbol"];
     [stock **=** setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:160] // use of undeclared identifier     'setObject'
              forKey:@"shares"];
```

Your code should be..

```
 [stock  setObject:@"GOOG" // use of undeclared identifier 'setObject'
                 forKey:@"symbol"];
     [stock  setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:160] // use of undeclared identifier     'setObject'
              forKey:@"shares"];
```

Comment: That did it; thank you. Must have been 'equals sign blindness'

Answer (score 1):

You do not do

`[stock = setObject....`

you directly do

`[stock setObject....`

These methods do not return any sort of value, they are void methods (talking about the -setObject method)

Comment: yea it even looks like you know what you're doing and its just a typo cuz higher in the code you do it properly xD

Answer (score 0):

You've got [stock = setObject instead of just  [stock setObject: Lose the equals.